# Uninstallation dialog doesnt appear when uninstallating from Control Panel

Tags: wix

When the setup is run by double-clicking then the setup dialog appears as expected. When I want to un-install by double-clicking the setup, then the setup dialog appears with options to Change, Repair and Remove. However, when I try to uninstall through Control Panel, the dialog doesnt appear and uninstallation kicks off. Same thing happens when I right click on the setup file and choose Uninstall. How do I make the dialog appear every time when an uninstall is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nithin when you try to uninstall through Control Panel, the dialog doesn't appear and uninstallation starts with Windows Installer progress bar dialog.
Yes, that's the default behavior of the Add/Remove Programs. It always 
uninstalls MSI packages in basic mode after prompting.
The only place you can author UI during an uninstall is a "change" or "maintenance" UI.
But there are some tricks to achieve it.
1> Bootstrapper which calls your MSI with the desired **UILevel** rather than allowing ARP call your MSI directly.
2> Set  **ARPNOREMOVE** property to force a user to use maintenance mode. But this would actually remove the option to Uninstall your product from both Control Panel and its Maintenance Dialog box.
so redefine **Maintenance Dialog** while enabling the Remove button forcefully using Condition element can do your work.
 **Farrukh Waheed** Tutorial [How to force GUI uninstall using ARPNOREMOVE property](http://devdare.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-force-gui-uninstall-using.html) can help you with same.

Comment: But I've found many products (ex: Notepad++) where the maintaince dialog appears when tried to uninstall from control panel. Also, the option available for this entry in control panel was "Uninstall/Change" rather than the usual "Uninstall" "Change" and "Repair". How do I make my product have options similar to Notepad++?